# Best way to merge multiple csv files starting with different timestamps using pandas concat

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

##### The dataset:

I have a collection csv files inside a folder with each csv file with title: `timestamp` and `close`. Each file is saved as `{symbol}.csv` where symbols range from a list of symbols eg: `['ADAUSDT', 'MAGICUSDT', 'LUNCUSDT', 'LINAUSDT', 'LEVERUSDT', 'BUSDUSDT', BTSUSDT, ALGOUSDT]`.... In reality I have over 100+ symbols

Here's the link to [sample csv files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1U5FdC-sSQqWJHgj8GpKHtHV5glPlHim9?usp=sharing) incase you need them

##### What I would like to do:

I want to merge all the close prices inside these files into one data frame using pd.concat without losing much data. Most of the files start at a similar date, but some of them don't have much data back to 1 year (eg: LUNCUSDT) In those cases I want to find a way in which I can either drop those files and merge the rest depending on whether the rest of the dates all come within a close range.

If that is complicated maybe I would like to try to arrange them all together based on the most recent data. However, all the DateTime stamps in the last rows are also not in the same range.

I would appreciate any help on how I can approach this logic. Thanks in advance.

##### Here's my attempt:

```
symbols = pd.read_csv('symbols.csv')
symbols = symbols.symbols.to_list()

merged_df = pd.DataFrame()
for symbol in symbols:
    
    df = pd.read_csv(f"OHLC/5m/{symbol}.csv", usecols=[0,4])
    df = df.rename(columns={'close': symbol})
    #df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')
    merged_df = pd.concat([merged_df, df], axis=1)

merged_df
```

This unfortunately prints an uneven dataframe, which also has repeating timestamp column. Therefore I do not know how I could figure out the latest and earliest time in the row:

```
    timestamp   ADAUSDT timestamp   XRPUSDT timestamp   XLMUSDT timestamp   TRXUSDT timestamp   VETUSDT ... timestamp   LEVERUSDT   timestamp   STGUSDT timestamp   LUNCUSDT    timestamp   HFTUSDT timestamp   MAGICUSDT
0   2022-02-14 17:35:00 1.048   2022-02-14 17:35:00 0.7989  2022-02-14 17:35:00 0.2112  2022-02-14 17:35:00 0.06484 2022-02-14 17:35:00 0.05662 ... 2022-07-13 04:00:00 0.001252    2022-08-19 09:00:00 0.4667  2022-09-09 08:00:00 0.000529    2022-11-07 13:00:00 3.6009  2022-12-12 08:00:00 0.7873
1   2022-02-14 17:40:00 1.047   2022-02-14 17:40:00 0.7986  2022-02-14 17:40:00 0.2111  2022-02-14 17:40:00 0.06482 2022-02-14 17:40:00 0.05665 ... 2022-07-13 04:05:00 0.001249    2022-08-19 09:05:00 0.5257  2022-09-09 08:05:00 0.000522    2022-11-07 13:05:00 2.9160  2022-12-12 08:05:00 0.8116
2   2022-02-14 17:45:00 1.048   2022-02-14 17:45:00 0.7981  2022-02-14 17:45:00 0.2111  2022-02-14 17:45:00 0.06488 2022-02-14 17:45:00 0.05668 ... 2022-07-13 04:10:00 0.001320    2022-08-19 09:10:00 0.5100  2022-09-09 08:10:00 0.000517    2022-11-07 13:10:00 2.6169  2022-12-12 08:10:00 0.8064
3   2022-02-14 17:50:00 1.047   2022-02-14 17:50:00 0.7980  2022-02-14 17:50:00 0.2109  2022-02-14 17:50:00 0.06477 2022-02-14 17:50:00 0.05658 ... 2022-07-13 04:15:00 0.001417    2022-08-19 09:15:00 0.5341  2022-09-09 08:15:00 0.000520    2022-11-07 13:15:00 2.4513  2022-12-12 08:15:00 0.8035
4   2022-02-14 17:55:00 1.047   2022-02-14 17:55:00 0.7969  2022-02-14 17:55:00 0.2108  2022-02-14 17:55:00 0.06474 2022-02-14 17:55:00 0.05656 ... 2022-07-13 04:20:00 0.001400    2022-08-19 09:20:00 0.6345  2022-09-09 08:20:00 0.000527    2022-11-07 13:20:00 2.5170  2022-12-12 08:20:00 0.8550
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
105123  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
105124  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
105125  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
105126  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
105127  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thankyou!

Comment: Given that you have so many symbols, perhaps you may want to consider instead of concat'ing along axis=1, to concat along axis=0 (i.e., the default axis). You would add a new column called symbol to differentiate what symbol the row is referring to.

Your current approach of horizontal concating is not optimal for time series data that arrives at irregular intervals, as it would result in a lot of NaNs or duplicate data.

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

Your test implementation attempts to perform a horizontal concat. However, I think you should consider a vertical concat instead - and indeed, the title of your question is simply "best way to merge multiple csv files with different timestamps"

The advantage of using the standard vertical concat is that for time series datasets that arrives at irregular intervals, it is far more memory efficient. You've already touched a little bit on the issues that you would run into doing a horizontal concat in your example - multiple timestamp columns, one for each csv.

A better approach might be to add an additional column called `symbol` to differentiate each row, and a vertical concat like so

```py
symbols = pd.read_csv('symbols.csv')
symbols = symbols.symbols.to_list()

dfs = []
for symbol in symbols:
    df = pd.read_csv(f"OHLC/5m/{symbol}.csv", usecols=[0,4])
    df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')

    # adds symbol as a column
    df['symbol'] = symbol

merged_df = pd.concat(dfs).set_index('timestamp').sort_index()
```

Now, your merged df will look something like this

```
+-----------+-------+--------+
| timestamp | close | symbol |
+-----------+-------+--------+
|...........|.......|........|
+----------------------------+
```

## Option 2

If you still want to do a horizontal concat, you could try to take advantage of merge_asof instead to get things on the same row.

To get back into the realm of regular intervals, you could use pandas' `date_range` to generate a periodic column, and then merge_asof every csv file back into it.

```py
symbols = pd.read_csv('symbols.csv')
symbols = symbols.symbols.to_list()

df_merged = pd.DataFrame(
    data=pd.date_range(start='1/1/2023', end='1/2/2023', freq='T'),
    columns=['time']
).set_index('time') # required for merge_asof

for symbol in symbols:
    df = pd.read_csv(f"OHLC/5m/{symbol}.csv", usecols=[0,4])
    df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')
    df = df.set_index('timestamp') # required for merge_asof

    df_merged = pd.merge_asof(
        left=df_merged,
        right=df.rename(columns={'close': symbol}),
        left_index=True,
        right_index=True,
    )
```

## Option 3

If you're ok with using a huge amount of memory, you can simply merge every dataframe as you are already doing, and then fillna with the bfill argument

Comment: This is nice, however, it would not be the ideal dataset I can pass to the rest of my tasks as I will have to change everything else to adapt to this dataset, there must be a better way. I'll keep trying on my end, I need the close prices side by side, hence why I decided to go with axis =1. But thank you for your suggestion and answer!

Comment: If you are OK with sampling at regular intervals, you could also generate a synthetic column of timestamps at some fixed interval (say, every N seconds), and then merge_asof every other dataframe back into the first one.